# how do I activate the INSERT module?

Tags: 7, media, javascript

i want to use the INSERT module, to be abel to insert images into my content in a WYSIWYG style. I have downloaded & installed colorbox, have added a new field to my content type that allows me to upload images, I have installed CKEditor and [Insert](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert) but when I upload a image in my added field, I do not get an *insert* button to place the image into my content. What am I missing?

Comment: Check field settings for both text and image fields, and look for errors in js console of your browser. What you're missing should be somewhere there.

Comment: it'll likely be something you may need to configure within CKeditor for the Insert Button to appear on the toolbar. You can configure such settings by going to http://yoursite.com/admin/config/content/ckeditor

Comment: @th0ward Insert button does **not** appear in CKeditor, it appears next to image. Unless there is something I'm not yet aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing to check `Enable insert button` under the **INSERT** settings in my image field configuration where yo also select the **Enabled Insert styles**